# Laravel - store uint8 in database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting data from a JSON API that also returns objects with huge numbers (uint8). Here's an example:

```
      {
      "chordID": "d7604de9aa22e2626a690fb0b3ec2c4ef4c790d73679e56ce0d5fa2f77befba0",
      "consensusData": 11689184649718456000,
      "hash": "c785277874464590ce77b2e59df198a670ba8807f51ce2a6f4b32f38033ac4f8",
      "height": 1,
      "nextBookKeeper": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "prevBlockHash": "1a4f55a1164ea4b8de29484eb790bffa3f5b1a7ccbc3f323142aa1ae3e93b742",
      "program": {
        "code": "00",
        "parameter": "00"
      },
      "signature": "3f2f01c72a3f1a00a54cf72a6fa1c28b64ac1f9bd4c06303591e20b1846c13a0b86de04c67bcb526184a92f1f697f884b8ae88a4c80eb3076d0a8a18dbb52403",
      "signer": "040149c42944eea91f094c16538eff0449d4d1e236f31c8c706b2e40e98402984c",
      "stateRoot": "1966dbb876e96c4fa8c77490548c00014607ab8050014588f209451cd19a1b1a",
      "timestamp": 1553077869,
      "transactionsRoot": "578a7b6b1802effaa8a4cca5d56cb0b6c37bd6ce830496dc3d2f546bf1ed48c8",
      "version": 1,
      "winnerHash": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "winnerType": "GenesisSigner"
    }
```

Now I want to directly save this data through:

```
 $transaction = new Transaction($response["result"]);
```

Here Laravel runs into an error because the number gets converted to exponential writing:

```
array:15 [
  "chordID" => "d7604de9aa22e2626a690fb0b3ec2c4ef4c790d73679e56ce0d5fa2f77befba0"
  "consensusData" => 1.1689184649718E+19
  "hash" => "c785277874464590ce77b2e59df198a670ba8807f51ce2a6f4b32f38033ac4f8"
  "height" => 1
  "nextBookKeeper" => "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  "prevBlockHash" => "1a4f55a1164ea4b8de29484eb790bffa3f5b1a7ccbc3f323142aa1ae3e93b742"
  "program" => array:2 [
    "code" => "00"
    "parameter" => "00"
  ]
  "signature" => "3f2f01c72a3f1a00a54cf72a6fa1c28b64ac1f9bd4c06303591e20b1846c13a0b86de04c67bcb526184a92f1f697f884b8ae88a4c80eb3076d0a8a18dbb52403"
  "signer" => "040149c42944eea91f094c16538eff0449d4d1e236f31c8c706b2e40e98402984c"
  "stateRoot" => "1966dbb876e96c4fa8c77490548c00014607ab8050014588f209451cd19a1b1a"
  "timestamp" => 1553077869
  "transactionsRoot" => "578a7b6b1802effaa8a4cca5d56cb0b6c37bd6ce830496dc3d2f546bf1ed48c8"
  "version" => 1
  "winnerHash" => "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  "winnerType" => "GenesisSigner"
]
```

Here is my DB Schema:

```
 Schema::create('headers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('block_id');
            $table->binary('hash');
            $table->integer('version')->unsigned();
            $table->binary('prevBlockHash');
            $table->binary('transactionsRoot');
            $table->binary('stateRoot');
            $table->bigInteger('timestamp');
            $table->integer('height')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('consensusData')->unsigned();
            $table->binary('nextBookKeeper');
            $table->binary('winnerHash');
            $table->enum('winnerType', ['GenesisSigner', 'TxnSigner', 'BlockSigner']);
            $table->binary('signer');
            $table->binary('chordID');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('block_id')
            ->references('id')->on('blocks')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Is there any way to prevent that casting by default or is there a fix for that? I'm using pgsql database with my laravel backend.

Comment: Save it as `LONGTEXT` and you're in the clear.

Comment: That number is 1.26 times the maximum integer storage value of 9223372036854775807 in pgsql... What is the significance of that number? Can it be stored as `text`?

Comment: sure, it can be stored as a text. It basically comes from a LevelDB and is only used for displaying, not for calculating.